# Join one row to multiple rows in another table

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join, group-concat

I have a table to entities (lets call them people) and properties (one person can have an arbitrary number of properties). Ex:

### People

```
Name  Age
--------
Jane  27
Joe   36
Jim   16
```

### Properties

```
Name   Property
-----------------
Jane   Smart
Jane   Funny
Jane   Good-looking
Joe    Smart
Joe    Workaholic
Jim    Funny
Jim    Young
```

I would like to write an efficient select that would select people based on age and return all or some of their properties.

```
Ex: People older than 26
Name Properties
Jane Smart, Funny, Good-looking
Joe Smart, Workaholic
```

It's also acceptable to return one of the properties and total property count.

The query should be efficient: there are millions of rows in people table, hundreds of thousands of rows in properties table (so most people have no properties). There are hundreds of rows selected at a time.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Are you looking to get a comma separated list of properties? Also, do you need to specify which properties you would like to see? I.e. "People older than 26 who are funny and good looking"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT x.name,
          GROUP_CONCAT(y.property SEPARATOR ', ')
     FROM PEOPLE x
LEFT JOIN PROPERTIES y ON y.name = x.name
    WHERE x.age > 26
 GROUP BY x.name
```

You want the MySQL function GROUP_CONCAT ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)) in order to return a comma separated list of the PROPERTIES.property value.

I used a LEFT JOIN rather than a JOIN in order to include PEOPLE records that don't have a value in the PROPERTIES table - if you only want a list of people with values in the PROPERTIES table, use:

```
   SELECT x.name,
          GROUP_CONCAT(y.property SEPARATOR ', ')
     FROM PEOPLE x
     JOIN PROPERTIES y ON y.name = x.name
    WHERE x.age > 26
 GROUP BY x.name
```

I realize this is an example, but using a name is a poor choice for referencial integrity when you consider how many "John Smith"s there are.  Assigning a user_id, being a unique value per user, would be a better choice.

Comment: @meriton: I'd like have both columns in the PROPERTIES table as the primary key.

Comment: Right, that is even better than just blindly following the "every foreign key should have an index" rule :-)

Comment: If anyone happens across this question and is using an Oracle DB, there is an equivalent LISTAGG function (since Oracel 11.2 I think): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm

Comment: @CodeClimber: The question is tagged for MySQL, not Oracle.

Comment: @OMGPonies Yep, I'm aware of that. Not trying to answer the question, just help out anyone who ends up here with a similar query on an Oracle DB.

Comment: @OMGPonies FWIW, I found it helpful. BTW the link is broken, the new one is https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT x.name,(select GROUP_CONCAT(y.Properties SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM PROPERTIES y 
WHERE y.name.=x.name ) as Properties FROM mst_People x
```

try this

Answer (score 3):

You can use `INNER JOIN` to link the two tables together. [More info on JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

```
SELECT *
FROM People P
INNER JOIN Properties Pr
  ON Pr.Name = P.Name
WHERE P.Name = 'Joe' -- or a specific age, etc
```

However, it's often a lot faster to add a unique [primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) to tables like these, and to create an [index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) to increase speed.

Say the table `People` has a field `id`
And the table `Properties` has a field `peopleId` to link them together

Then the query would then look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM People P
INNER JOIN Properties Pr
  ON Pr.id = P.peopleId
WHERE P.Name = 'Joe'
```