# Oracle sql query, one row matches to multiple in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help to create an sql query on Oracle.

I am looking to do the exact same thing as shown in this thread

[Join one row to multiple rows in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892816/join-one-row-to-multiple-rows-in-another-table)

This thread is done in MySql, whereas I need to do it with Oracle.

Thanks for the help

Comment: and you wrote group_concat yourself, but it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: And what have you tried? What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

This is a poor way to ask question but I think this is what you need.

After 11gr2, you can use `LISTAGG`, documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm).

For lower versions, use `wm_concat` but it's not documented. There are many examples in web for both cases, since you didn't provide enough information I can't give you an example. Just see for yourself and match your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.name,
      wmsys.wm_concat (y.property)
 FROM PEOPLE x
LEFT JOIN PROPERTIES y ON y.name = x.name
WHERE x.age > 26
GROUP BY x.name
```